# Pesquisa usando model

Tags: php, laravel, oracle

Gostaria de usar o meu model para fazer pesquisa no Laravel.

Gostaria que, se possível, algum pudesse me explicar:

Tenho minha model

```
class minhaModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = "minha_model";
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'ID_CAMPO';
    public $incrementing = false;
    public $sequence = 'MINHA_SEQUENCIA';
}
```

O que eu quero saber é porque isso aqui funciona:

```
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    /* ... */
    $model = DB::select( 'SELECT * FROM minha_model WHERE campo1 = ?', array( $codigo ) )
```

E isso aqui não funciona:

```
   use App\HamOcorrenciasAnvisa;
   /* ... */
   $model = MinhaModel::where( 'campo1', $codigo );
```

A tabela é:

```
id_campo | campo1 | campo2
  1      |  123   |  321
  2      |  222   |  333
```

Estou começando com Laravel.

Comment: E se fizeres: `$model = MinhaModel::where( 'campo1', $codigo )->get();`?

Comment: Isso mesmo.. Deu certinho. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Pode adicionar resposta, por favor

Comment: Colocada em baixo (; , obgado pelo requisito da resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na realidade está tudo bem, mas incompleto.

Neste momento:

```
$model = MinhaModel::where( 'campo1', $codigo );
```

Apenas ficas com o [Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries), não estás ainda a extrair os resultados, para isso precisas só de acresentar `->get();`:

```
$model = MinhaModel::where( 'campo1', $codigo )->get();
```

Comment: que show essa resposta